# iOS app exits before launch

Tags: ios

I am new to iOS development and as a newbie I’ve created a very simple Hello World application using Xcode 4.3.3 against iOS 5.0 SDK on my MacBook air. I have set **Deployment Target** to **3.2** and **Base SDK** (in *build settings*) has been set to **iOS 5.1**

The output build runs fine on iPhone 4.3 simulator but when I copy output HelloWorld.app to my jailbroken iPod using a SSH client the app icon appears however when I run it, the app exits before launch.
My iPod OS version is **4.2.1** and I can run a lot of app from cydia however it sounds like I’m missing something when I build my own app.

Valid Architecture is set to **armv6 armv7**

Is there anybody help me with that?

Comment: I suggest looking at console messages from your iPod to see if there are any clues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The executable that is deployed to the Simulator cannot be just copied to a device. Xcode should do it for you and it needs a development certificate. There is a way, however, to patch Xcode to do it without certificate, but you have to search how to do it.

Comment: you mean I have to certified my app before deployment?

Comment: No I mean, that the bundle compiled for the Simulator cannot run on the device. It's just compiled in a different way, because the Simulator is not an emulator of the iPhone. The official way to test on your device is to have a development certificate.

Comment: I assumed that if he built for arm that it was not a simulator bundle.  (?)